# Mount wp-content folder with gcsfuse

Tags: mount, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

How do I mount a wp-content folder (wordpress) so the permissions stay in place and the web server can serve the files from the sub directory?

Problem I am facing are:

- `gcsfuse bucketname /var/www/html/wp-content`

  - wp-content folder everything is root and wordpress doesn't find theme folders
- fstab `bucketname /var/www/html/wp-content gcsfuse rw,uid=1001,gid=33`

  - correct users as owners but wordpress fails with a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure the "user_allow_other" row in the /etc/fuse.conf file is uncommented.

Then mount using --dir-mode and the option allow_other:

```
gcsfuse --dir-mode "777" -o allow_other bucket-name mounting
```